# SheepShaver - cdenable.sys on 64-bit

Tags: emulation, mac-os-classic, sheepshaver

I am using SheepShaver to emulate OS9 and I have got everything else working, except that when I run it it gives me the cdenable.sys is missing error. I have cdenable.sys in Windows/System32/drivers, and it doesn't work.

I am on Windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Basilisk II?  If so, it should be included in SheepShaver.

Download `cdenable.sys` from one of the SheepShaver links [here](http://www.emaculation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5325).  Then copy the file from the `CD-ROM Drivers` directory to `..WINDOWS\system32\drivers`.

[Source](http://www.emaculation.com/doku.php/cdenable.sys)

Actually, from that article it looks like this driver is only supported on 32-bit versions of Windows.

On 64-bit versions of Windows, put the driver in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\drivers` directory.

Comment: I'm using SheepShaver to use OS9 and I have cdenable.sys in that directory.

Comment: @JordanM.Baron try the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\drivers` directory instead.